# How can I change the OS Disk size in Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure

I use a virtual machine in Azure. However, the cost of storage is much more than the virtual machine. How can I reduce the storage limit while creating a virtual machine?

Comment: What is the current size of your OSDisk?

Comment: 127 gb and its too many for me. costs unnecessarily. Virtual machine cost $ 25 this month but storage costs $ 100

Comment: Can you include details on the type of VM and storage that you are using?

Comment: Plan: B1ms 2 vcpu 2 gb ram.
Storage: 127 gb
Virtual machine cost: 25$
Storage cost: 99$

I dont need much storage. Cost are so high. I want drop cost of VM
Sorry for English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **Azure Smaller Disk** images while creating a Virtual Machine.

> You cannot resize the OS down, only up. So this is not possible.
>
> If you want a Windows Server with a 40GB OS disk, Microsoft actually
> have a specific image for that in the Azure Marketplace. They all have
> [small disks] in the title

Refer this - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/new-smaller-windows-server-iaas-image/

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ankush. I use Windows 10. I ll check to marketplace